# Why jquery click each time an increasing value of?

Tags: jquery

After each toggle `$(".pages a").click (function () {};` adding text box, an increasing number of. If you toggle the condition runs three times, adding an extra three link. What is the solution? My jquery code has the following structure:

Note: `if (go=="page") {}` required to use in

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.page = {

        come: function(go) {
            var links = $("textarea[name=links]");
            if(go == "page") {

                $('.pages').toggle();

                $('.pages span').click(function() {
                    $('.pages').hide();
                });

                $(".pages a").click(function() {

                    var pg = $(this).attr('href');
                    var links2 = $(links).val();
                    $(links).val(links2 + pg);

                });
            }
        }

    }

});
```

Comment: (At least for me) it is not clear what you want to do. Can you explain a bit more detailed what you want to achieve?

Comment: If you toggle the condition runs three times, adding an extra three link. I want to only one link added.

Comment: my problem not solved. please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have extracted your toggle's  `$(".pages a")` as below and try to use the way which I showed.

```
$(".pages a").unbind('click').bind('click', function () {

    var pg = $(this).attr('href');
    var links2 = $(links).val();
    $(links).val(links2 + pg);

    return false; //to prevent the browser actually following the links
       });
```

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: Awesome @Sampath :) This problem is solved. Thank you very much.